# Sending DTMF tones in between outgoing call create call in 3 way mode in android

Tags: android, dtmf

When an outgoing call event fire, after sometime call is sending DTMF tones, but when DTMF tones send, previous call is going to hold and new call is generated, and generate 3 way calling in android.
What can I do that call is not generate 3 way code?

**Code of sending DTMF is:**

```
ToneGenerator tone = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF,ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME >> 1);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_2);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_3);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_4);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_5);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_6);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_7);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_8);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_9);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_P);
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_S);

tone.stopTone();

concatenate_tonevalue = ("tel://");

for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {

        value = String.valueOf(param.charAt(i));

        try {
            parsetonevalue = Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        tonea = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0;
        toneb = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1;
        tonec = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_2;
        toned = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_3;
        tonee = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_4;
        tonef = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_5;
        toneg = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_6;
        toneh = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_7;
        tonei = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_8;
        tonej = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_9;
        tonek = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_P;
        tonel = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_S;

        /* compare dialed value with tone generator value */

        if (parsetonevalue == tonea) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(tonea) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == toneb) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(toneb) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == tonec) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(tonec) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == toned) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(toned) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == tonee) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(tonee) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == tonef) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(tonef) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == toneg) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(toneg) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == toneh) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(toneh) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == tonei) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(tonei) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == tonej) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(tonej) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == tonek) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(tonek) + ",";

        } else if (parsetonevalue == tonel) {

            concatenate_tonevalue += String.valueOf(tonel) + ",";

        }
    }

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(concatenate_tonevalue + ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_P);

    MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
    activity.finish();


    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
            startActivity(i);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Using DTMF this way, you're creating a mix of multiple calls and multiple audible playback of DTMF, which happens to be a wrong way for android;